# Filter a table in AppScript ignoring the first row (column names)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Because of the issues Google Sheets has with the ImportRange function, I wanted to create an AppScript to replace the ImportRange. I am new into JS but currently, I have the following:

```
function My_ImportRange() {

  var clearContent = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet 1").getDataRange().clearContent()

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet-id').
  getSheetByName('name').getRange('A:AI').getValues();

  // filtering data

  var filtered_values = values.filter(filterlogic)

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet 1').
  getRange(2,1,filtered_values.length,filtered_values[0].length).setValues(filtered_values);

}

var filterlogic = function(item){
  return item[0] === "filter 1" &&
  item[6] === "filter 2";};
```

The issue I have is that when **I filter the table (with the filterlogic function), the first row or column names get dropped off because of the filter** .

How can I tell the filter to only run the logic from the 2nd row, ignoring the column names?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet?

Comment: here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SpEmbSKketusgExmKc0h_h9cyn8mpyCa6GNOJa2ojDQ/edit#gid=0 i hope it helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the script below.

Remove the header using `shift` and add it back after filtering using `unshift`

```
// assuming data is in Sheet1 A:H
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange('A:H').getValues();
// remove headers before filtering
var headers = values.shift();

// filter values
var filtered_values = values.filter(filterlogic)
// append back the headers in the first row after filtering
filtered_values.unshift(headers);

Logger.log(filtered_values)
```

OR tell the filter to exclude index 0 which should be the first row.

If we filter "A" and 10 for column A and G:

```
var filterlogic = function(item, index){
  // return true IF condition is met OR index is 0 or the first row.
  return (item[0] === "A" && item[6] === 10) || index == 0;
};
```

Both of modification will exclude the 1st element in values which is the 1st row. Choose what you think is best. Both will return the same data.

[image]

Comment: didn't work :( . It is still dropping off the column names (which is the first row). I need that row to stay after the filter.

Comment: I have misunderstood your question. @joseGajardo, kindly see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! it worked!